# Read multiple files from a list of directory Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of directories with same structure/same file name. Under each there are files with different types and each directory has the same file names (number of files may vary) but different contents.

```
parentDIR-
     - subDir1
       - file1.ext1 (contains taskID)
       - file2.ext2 (contains userID)
       - file3.ext3
     - subDir2
       - file1.ext1 (contains taskID)
       - file2.ext2 (contains userID)
       - file3.ext3
     - subDir100
```

How do I search all the directories and extract taskID and userID as a pair from file1/file2? I need the file1/file2 in the same directory to be opened/closed properly and read the contents because they have some information shared in common.

I am thinking to use

glob, with xxxx as, ExitStack(), but not sure how to connect them all together

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in `glob`

```
In [1]: import glob
   ...: for x in glob.glob('parent/**/*.ext[1|2]', recursive=True):
   ...:     # Open, read content close here
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:
parent/subdir2/file1.ext1
parent/subdir2/file2.ext2
parent/subdir1/file1.ext1
parent/subdir1/file2.ext2
```

Comment: thanks, in my case, ext1, ext2 are actually quite different pattern, e.g., abc.xy1, cde.dat.zst etc

Comment: @tudou you can customize the regex as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach

```
types={"*.ext1", "*.ext2"}

for type in types:
    path(dir_name).rglob(type):
        do_something
```